# Error in grid.Call using ggsave, save_plot, etc

Tags: r, ggplot2, rstudio, cairo

I just updated R and Rstudio to version 3.6.1 and 1.2.5, respectively. Now when I generate a plot with ggplot2 and try to save it as I used to do, I get this error:

```
Error in grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  : 
X11 font -adobe-helvetica-%s-%s-*-*-%d-*-*-*-*-*-*-*, face 1 at size 11 could not be loaded
```

my capabilities():

```
jpeg         png        tiff       tcltk         X11        aqua    http/ftp     sockets      libxml        fifo 
   TRUE        TRUE       FALSE       FALSE        TRUE       FALSE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE 
 cledit       iconv         NLS     profmem       cairo         ICU long.double     libcurl 
   TRUE        TRUE        TRUE       FALSE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE
```

If I try:

```
X11(type="cairo")
```

Nothing happens, only a blank window.

I'm working in an Ubuntu 16.04 device.

Comment: Hard to diagnose without a full reproducible example. Have you checked to ensure that you have the "Adobe Helvetica" font on your system?

Comment: Are you looking for this [ask ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/449578/x11-font-adobe-helvetica-s-s-d-face-2-at-size-11-could-no) question?

Comment: @jdobres Helvetica is dated anyways. Try [Hellvetica](https://hellveticafont.com/) !